# Adding a class to the second next sibling class or the second previous sibling class

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to add a class to the second next o the second previous class of a class?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="">A</div>
    <div class="">B</div>
    <div class="active">C</div>
    <div class="">D</div>
    <div class="">E</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I want to add a class to "A" div when "C" has .active, what should I do?

Or add a class to "E" div when "C" has .active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jquery you can chain `next()` and `prev()` to archieve this

```js
console.log($('.active').next().next().html())
console.log($('.active').prev().prev().html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="">A</div>
  <div class="">B</div>
  <div class="active">C</div>
  <div class="">D</div>
  <div class="">E</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to keep updating this code, in my case .active is a dynamic class.

Comment: When you only have this Body and the 5 divs with nth child of you can geht all your loops and Loop until the mid x/2+1 to get the middlest element